# End point not found in WCF

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, json, json.net

I have created one WCF service for Insert, update, Delete, and retrieve data. In IService1.cs file I have following code. where I am declaring five methods.

```
public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "getInfo")]
        CustomerData Get();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "GetJson")]
        String GetJson();

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Insert")]
        void Insert(string name, string country);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Update")]
        void Update(int customerId, string name, string country);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Delete")]
        void Delete(int customerId); 
}
[DataContract]
    public class CustomerData
    {
        public CustomerData()
        {
            this.CustomersTable = new DataTable("CustomersData");
        }

        [DataMember]
        public DataTable CustomersTable { get; set; }
    }
```

I have just created one method called "GetJson" to get data from database table  and convert it into Json strig and return it.

In Service1.svc.cs file I have following code.

```
public class Service1 : IService1
    {
 public CustomerData Get()
        {
            String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblCustomers", con))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            CustomerData customer = new CustomerData();
                            da.Fill(customer.CustomersTable);
                            return customer;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public String GetJson()
        {
            String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblCustomers", con))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            CustomerData customer = new CustomerData();
                            da.Fill(customer.CustomersTable);
                            String JsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer.CustomersTable);
                            return JsonString;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public void Insert(String name, String country)
        {
            String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tblCustomers(Name, Country) values(@name,@country)", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", country);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        public void Update(int customerId, string name, string country)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblCustomers SET Name = @Name, Country = @Country WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId"))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerId", customerId);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", country);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        public void Delete(int customerId)
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tblCustomers WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId"))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerId", customerId);
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

In "GetJson" method datatable is converted into Json String.

> String JsonString =
>   JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer.CustomersTable);
>
> return JsonString;

in Web.config file following code

```
<configuration>   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBCS" connectionString="data source=.\MSSQL; database=Customers; integrated security=SSPI"/>   </connectionStrings> <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />   </system.web>   <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService2.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfService2.Service1Behavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="REST" contract="WcfService2.IService1"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfService2.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="REST">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />   </system.serviceModel>  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>   </system.webServer> </configuration>
```

This web service successfully hosted on IIS 7.5 but when I try to run

> http://localhost/WcfService2/Service1.svc/GetJson

***It displays error "Endpoint not found". I think problem in Web.config file***

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService2.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfService2.Service1Behavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="REST" contract="WcfService2.IService1"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfService2.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="REST">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I am using Advance Rest Client in crome. It works fine for Insert, Update, delete but when I try to select something like "select * from tblCustomer" and retrieve data from database and return it into JSON format then error occur.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicated `behaviorConfiguration` atribute in `service` tag.

Try to delete `behaviorConfiguration="WcfService2.Service1Behavior"`.

Comment: try to debug your GetJson method step by step